# Invalid command 'define', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Tags: apache, module

I'm getting error:

> Invalid command 'define', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

when I use `define variable value` in .conf file of apache 2.2.15.

I'm not finding correct help on net. 
Can anyone suggest which module do I need to install and how?

Comment: Define was introduced by Apache 2.4. For Apache < 2.4, you need to use -D option to the command line which starts Apache. See details in [doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#define).

Comment: Thank you Julp for reply. This helps me.
Can I use customised (non-standard) parameter to -D? like -DNode
I want to define variable $Node which should held value 1 or 2.
Many Thanks,
Sadashiv

Comment: Where do you want to use it after? `-D` just define a named parameter without a value. Without upgrading to a 2.4 version, a solution may be to use a variable environment as Apache inherits them at its start and can be as well substituted in any of its configuration files (.htaccess included). But this can be "tricky" to do if this is not planned in the first place (Windows in particular) ; Debian, for example, do this via /etc/apache2/envvars (eg: if you add a line `export FOO=BAR`,to it, you can then use the variable `${FOO}` in Apache)

Comment: I'm using RHEL 6.6 with apache 2.2.15
In one of .conf file I want to use 
'define node 2'

This is not possible as I'm using apache 2.2 and upgrade not possible sooner.
Earlier I tried export but it was not working. I'll try it once again and get back to soon.

Comment: use of export is not allowed in any of file which load by http

Comment: Normal. I don't know RHEL but you need to identify (if there is one) the script that is sourced before Apache start. Is it /etc/sysconfig/httpd?

Comment: Julp, **Thank you very much.** You deserve treat from me.
It worked :) Filename is correct.
This is my first question on SO, is there anyway, I can say thank you to you? and mark this question as resolved?